# Run Node script and put the files inside dist folder into a dist branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to to do `npm run build` on push which which will create dist folder with multiple files inside it. I want to push those files to dist branch. If branch not present create it. dist branch commit message should link to commit I did in main branch that triggered this action.

Comment: I see a list of requirements, but no _question_ - what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?